# Differences between AddSignalR and AddSignalRCore extension methods in aspnet core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-2.1

I 'm trying to configure SignalR in my aspnet core 2.1 project.In Startup.cs class ,in ConfigureServices() method there are 2 options to use.

```
services.AddSignalR()
services.AddSignalRCore()
```

What are the differences between these 2 methods?

I was easily able to work with signalR with `services.AddSignalR()` but when i changed it to `services.AddSignalRCore()` it throw an error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`AddSignalR()` calls two more additional services than `AddSignalRCore()` as follows:

Here is the code of `AddSignalR()` method:

```cs
public static ISignalRBuilder AddSignalR(this IServiceCollection services, Action<HubOptions> configure)
{
    services.Configure(configure);
    services.AddSockets();
    return services.AddSignalRCore();
}
```

And here is the code of `AddSignalRCore()` method:

```cs
public static ISignalRBuilder AddSignalRCore(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(HubLifetimeManager<>), typeof(DefaultHubLifetimeManager<>));
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(IHubProtocolResolver), typeof(DefaultHubProtocolResolver));
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(IHubContext<>), typeof(HubContext<>));
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(HubEndPoint<>), typeof(HubEndPoint<>));
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IHubActivator<>), typeof(DefaultHubActivator<>));
    
    services.AddAuthorization();
    
    return new SignalRBuilder(services);
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. I wonder why Microsoft decides to implement it this way.

Comment: I think because if you want to conditionally enable/disable SignalR (my case). If you omit `AddSignalR()` and inject `IHubContext<T>` on your Controller app raise and `Exception`. Call `AddSignalRCore()` **dont instantiate the WebSocket** BUT resolve correctly the `IHubContext`

Comment: Probably shouldn't use it cuz all it does is throw null.

Comment: thanks but like wtf